# Question regarding Catalan Number

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

I have a question regarding Catalan Number. The question is as follows,

> Find the number of binary strings $w$ of length $2n$ with an equal number
>   of $1’$s and $0’$s and the property that every prefix of $w$ has at least as
>   many as $0’$s as $1’$s.

Now I know the answer for this question is $\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}.$ I wanted to know how this question relates to Catalan number?

I know this interpretation of lattice paths, But my question is how is this generalization can be used for this question?

To find the ways without touching the diagonal is =

> $\binom{2n}{n} - \binom{2n}{n-1},$ where $\binom{2n}{n-1}$ is the number of violating paths.

so to find the answer for the sequence question we have to take all the length $2n$ strings with an equal number of $1’$s and $0’$s which is  $\binom{2n}{n}.$ But the answer is $\binom{2n}{n} - \binom{2n}{n-1}.$ We know for the lattice path problem that $\binom{2n}{n-1}$ is the number of violating paths, but what is this $\binom{2n}{n-1}$ for this particular question?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format questions on this site.

Comment: will do from now on. thank you sir.

Comment: The answer is all contained in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), see the section on Dyck words.

Answer (score 1):

It the number of "violating words,"  the strings with an equal number of $0's$ and $1'$s where some prefix has more $1'$s than $0'$s.  Interpret $0$ as a move up and $1$ as a move to the right to see the equivalence with the lattice path problem.